# ¿Como presionar 2 veces o 3 un boton y cambie de color de acuerdo a las veces que lo presione vb?

Tags: vb, visual-studio-2013

ese es el codigo pero no se como hacer que cambie 2 veces o mas

```
 Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click
        Me.btn1.BackColor = Color.Red
        If btn1.BackColor = Color.Red Then

        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes definir una variable que usaras como contador:

```
Dim Counter As Integer
```

Esta variable puedes incrementarla, en este ejemplo cuando sea igual a 3 cambia el color, puedes reiniciar la variable para que cambie nuevamente al color inicial.

```
    If (Counter = 2) Then
        btnHi.BackColor = Color.Red
        Counter = 0  'Reinicia
    Else
        btnHi.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Counter += 1 'Incrementa
    End If
```